# R.android drawable not public

Tags: android, icons, drawable

I'd like to use the following icon from the android.R folder. Eclipse is saying it's not public. How can i use this icon.

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_invite"/>
```

Comment: create a copy in your own res folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every image that ships with the OS is considered part of the Android SDK. You will not find `ic_menu_invite` in [the SDK listing of what is part of the `android.R.drawable` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html).

However, as Doomsknight points out, you are welcome to copy the images from your SDK installation, or the AOSP, and put them in your project. For menu icons, this can get a bit tricky, in that there are stylistic differences in these icons in different Android versions, so between those and different icons for different densities, you will wind up copying a lot of images.

Comment: It is exactly that. But since AOSP's source is available... :)